# android Window Soft Input Mode

Tags: java, android, input, keyboard

In my app, I need to use EditText. But i have a problem with it. On some firmwares (Ice cream sandwich for example) when user click on edittext, keyboard pushes whole screen up! I want to turn it off.

I tried to add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize". Nothing changed.

Help me please.

Comment: You want to turn it off... ?you mean you don't want keyboard to show?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

That perfect work for you.

Comment: adjustPan option is working good on 4.0 devices and not working in 2.3 devices

Comment: @SoftwareSainath its support from API level 3.0 http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: Its supported from Android 3, not 3.0.  Android 2.3 is levels 9 and 10.  This is supported in 2.3

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Perfectly works for me. You try this one.